# Highcharts - Show the percentage difference between data points on a series

Tags: highcharts

I have a series of numbers I have plotted on a line chart. What I would like to do is show the percent difference between each subsequent data point in the series on the line plotted between each point. So my data looks something like this:

[10,15,20,25,30,35]

On the line between each point I want to show the percent difference between 10 and 15, or 50%, for example. Or between 20 and 25 (25%).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to calculate the series and override the dataLabels for that series:

```
$(function () {
    var data = [10,15,20,25,30,35]; // original data
    var data2 = [];  // calculated series
    var perDiff;  // percent difference
    for (var i=0;i<data.length-1;i++) {
        // calculate the % diff, we're going to use this as the point name
        perDiff  = (data[i+1] - data[i]) / data[i] * 100;
        data2.push({
            // this is assuming a category xAxis, if your original array has x & y values, you'll need to do a little more math
            x : i + 0.5,
            // find the half way mark
            y : (data[i] + data[i+1]) /2,
            // set the name, so we can use it in the dataLabel formatter
            name : Math.round(perDiff) + "%"
        });
    }
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Primary Axis'
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0
        }],
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
        },
        series: [{
            data: data,
            dataLabels : {
                enabled: true
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Percent Difference',
            data: data2,
            type: 'scatter',
            color: 'grey',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'grey',
                formatter : function() {
                    return this.point.name;
                }
            }

        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/xx84fwkp/1/

Comment: great solution Barbara!, I'd also guess that he wouldnt need this series on the legend, and it's markers on the charts. I'd add this :`marker{enabled:false,states :{hover:{ enabled:false }}}, showInLegend: false` to the series properties just to make things a little smoother :) http://jsfiddle.net/2s40p6m9/2/

Comment: Awesome solutions! Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, another question. So ultimately I am trying to load data from a Google spreadsheet. How would I go about loading that data into the variable? Would I just create another $('#container').highcharts( ) in the variable with the data I want?

Comment: You should ask that as another question. It's difficult to answer in comments and asking another question makes it searchable for others.  Are you using the google docs api to get the data? Can you get a Jason object of the Google spreadsheet

Comment: No. I was getting the data via the Highcharts method. But I'll make a new questions for it.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird: can you please see my question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588901/want-to-take-difference-between-single-series-data-and-show-them-on-chart-in-hig/39589875#39589875